# How to check for compilation error without generating the exe file with Mono (C#)

Tags: c#, compilation, mono

I need to compile a lot of C# files (hundreds of thousands of them). I use Mono and the mcs command generates automatically the exe file. It costs a lot of time because of the writing of the exe files.

Does the Mono compiler have a -fsyntaxonly like GCC ? I did research but I haven't found any clue.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Try the `--parse` command line argument. Its documentation says *Used for benchmarking. The compiler will only parse its input files.* Depending on what is meant by *parse*, it might do what you want.

Comment: It almost does what I want. With this argument `mcs` checks for lexical and syntactic errors but it seems that it doesn't check for semantics errors ...